# updating TFS from 2015 update 3 to 2015 update 4

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm preparing for upgrade tfs 2015 update 3 to tfs 2015 update 4.2.
There documentation file with all dll's and metadata who will affected by this upgrade?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2015-update4-vs

Comment: This is only about the bug that fixes in this upgrade. I need more details.

Comment: What do you need? What do you mean which dll’s will be affected?